# best fit img with caption into element

Tags: html, css, image, centering

Building an image slideshow, I have a container div of arbitrary size and aspect ratio into which I have to best fit an image, centred, with a caption overlayed at the bottom of the image and fitting its width. My best solution to date is to contain the image and the caption in a child element of the container but I'm having trouble centring it. This should be such a simple thing that I can't believe it's not staring me in the face but I can't see it. The code below uses a portrait format image but I need it to handle landscape also. I'm using React so jQuery is out.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 48vw;
  /* 4:3 */
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img-wrap {
  background-color: #efe;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.541)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fw800/background/20190223/ourmid/pngtree-full-aesthetic-aurora-night-sky-background-skystarry-skystarnight-viewbackgroundstar-image_87582.jpg" height="1600px">
    <div class="caption">Caption Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code like below:

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 48vw;
  /* 4:3 */
  margin: 5px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-wrap {
  background-color: #efe;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: contain; /*or cover if you want to cover all the area*/
  object-position: bottom;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.541)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/400/600.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption Content</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/600/300.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works perfectly for portrait format, on a landscape image the caption sits over the bottom of img-wrap, away from the image.

   <img src="https://cdn3.photoblogstop.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Sierra_HDR_DFX8048_2280x819_Q40_wm_mini-1726x819__-1140x541.jpg" width="1600px"/>

Comment: At the risk of sounding picky, could the image sit at the top, with the caption still overlaying it. It's not necessarily a huge problem, I could live with object-position: top and top: 0 on the caption.

Comment: @KimAldis I don't think so because the bottom distance won't be fixed and will change based on the image. You can use `object-fit:contain` and your image will cover all the are but will get cropped a bit on the sides

Comment: No problem, I'll live with caption top. You've been very helpful, many thanks, I've learned a  bit.

Answer (score 0):

don't `position absolute` the image,

also if the caption is the sibling of the image,

set the size of the parent and set the image as 100% if the parent's width and height

then you can simply use the `text-align: center` on the caption to center it.

edit :

- keep the existing style of a caption for positioning

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/hellooutlook/6ep4Lofz/4/

Comment: so I have to set the width and height of the parent based on the size of the image? That's proving a little difficult to work out given that it's all responsive. I could do that easily enough if I was using jQuery but React, I'm still finding my way around it.

Comment: The image is stretched horizontally.